# Get MavenProject from just the POM.xml - pom parser?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Is it possible to get an instance of `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject` or some other object form of the POM from just the pom.xml file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want it - what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

yes  you can . This is the code. You need maven-model-3.0.4.jar and plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar and maven-core-3.0.4.jar

```
Model model = null;
FileReader reader = null;
MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
try {
    reader = new FileReader(pomfile);
    model = mavenreader.read(reader);
    model.setPomFile(pomfile);
}catch(Exception ex){}
MavenProject project = new MavenProject(model);
```

Comment: Tried you solution but it doesn't populate some fields of the MavenProject object that I was expecting, like getCompileSourceRoots() returns empty list.

Comment: Reading a pom file does not involve interpolation of data such as variables, inherited settings from parents (and their proto-parents) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the MavenProject based on groupid, artifactId and version you have to run inside of a maven plugin. And this code will do the job:

```
ProjectBuildingRequest configuration = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest();
configuration.setProcessPlugins( false );
configuration.setRepositorySession( session );
org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact artifact = new org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact(groupId, artifactId, version, "compile", "", "", new DefaultArtifactHandler());
MavenProject project = projectBuilder.build(artifact, configuration).getProject();
```

The missing properties can be injected into the maven plugin.