# Maven plugin - how can I resolve properties for Maven Project created from pom file?

Tags: maven, properties, dependencies, dependency-properties, maven-plugin

I have a Maven Project that was created from a pom file as described in the following link:
[Get MavenProject from just the POM.xml - pom parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381460/get-mavenproject-from-just-the-pom-xml-pom-parser)
I have an unresolved dependency which I need to get values from. The values I get contain unresolved properties (for example: `<version>${version}</version>`).
project.getProperties does not return properties like `${project.build.directory}` or `${version}`
How can I get a list of ALL properties for this project?

for example I have this dependency and I cannot resolve it since `${version}` was not resolved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.comp.sp</groupId>
    <artifactId>art</artifactId>    
    <version>${version}</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve ?

Comment: the question was changed with an example. see above.

Comment: Hm..Ok. you are using a property as a version marker which does not work with Maven...So the question is: Why don't you put the version into the pom and things are done? or define a properties section in the pom itself ?

Comment: @khm variables in versions are fine, people do it all the time -- there are ways of messing up with it, of course.

Comment: @bmargulies I know...but i want to find out the reason for using them and reading the pom in that case..

Comment: OK, I see. user1116377, neither of us maven hackers here understand what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it. Could you just write a shell script that runs mvn dependency:list and parses the output?

Comment: I can't because I don't have a regular maven project. assume I have a pom file sent to me and using my plugin I need to create a MavenProject from it (no problem) and then resolve the dependencies (no problem too). The only issue is resolving the properties for the dependencies. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Aether library](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) which has examples in it which exactly solve your problem. (Take a look at [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git))..Officially [Aehter is in the meantime move to Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=technology.aether)

Comment: thank you, but I cannot use external libraries at the moment.

Comment: You can't use an external lib while building a maven plugin? Aether is part of maven!

Comment: @bmargulies i know...i simply oversight that there was maven plugin in the game..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/) util (I'm a developer), which is a wrapper around Apache Aether.