# Access maven properties defined in the pom

Tags: java, maven

How do I access maven properties defined in the pom in a normal maven project, and in a maven plugin project?

Comment: What kind of information are you interested in? If it's just versions or similar things, then it's probably a better idea to [put it in the manifest and read it from there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/how-to-get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime/2713013#2713013).

Comment: There is a lot of post in Stack Overflow about this : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+pom+in+java, at least, take a look before post. SO edit helpers should show them. Google too.

Comment: Thanks guys. I now realize this is really bad practice. Gonna try other approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MavenProject from just the POM.xml - pom parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381460/get-mavenproject-from-just-the-pom-xml-pom-parser)

Answer (score 89):

Use the [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to write specific pom `properties` to a file at compile time, and then read that file at run time.

In your **pom.xml**:

```xml
<properties>
     <name>${project.name}</name>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
     <foo>bar</foo>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/my.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then in **.java**:

```java
java.io.InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.properties");
java.util.Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(is);
String name = p.getProperty("name");
String version = p.getProperty("version");
String foo = p.getProperty("foo");
```

Comment: That worked, but made Eclipse fall into **infinite build / deploy-to-Tomcat loop** (build -> generate my.properties -> resource changed -> build), so I had to change phase to `compile`. Not sure if it's proper solution though.

Comment: @atoregozh suggested using Guava Resource's instead for loading the properties file. OK. But reverted change to keep this example minimal with standard API's.

Comment: A stable 1.0.0 version is available now

Answer (score 28):

Set up a [System variable from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project) and in java use [following call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)

```
System.getProperty("Key");
```

Comment: This will only work if you are running the resulting build from Maven, perhaps using the maven-exec-plugin. If you are just using Maven to compile the code, this will not work.

Comment: @DavidPashley, thats true. In the compile only case, I guess the variable needs to be set from the compiler plugin.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with standard java properties in combination with the `maven-resource-plugin` with enabled filtering on properties.

For more info see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

This will work for standard maven project as for plugin projects

Answer (score 7):

**Update for [Leif Gruenwoldt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52176/leif-gruenwoldt) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589696/10423604):**

It's important to use

```java
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("maven.properties");
```

instead of just

```java
 this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("maven.properties");
```

Especially, if you write your `maven.properties` file right to `project.build.outputDirectory`:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/maven.properties</outputFile>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Explanation is right [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource).

Comment: I tried your code and it generate the properties under the path classes, but when I try to retrieve it gives me null

Answer (score 6):

Maven already has a solution to do what you want:

[Get MavenProject from just the POM.xml - pom parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381460/get-mavenproject-from-just-the-pom-xml-pom-parser)

btw: first hit at google search ;)

```
Model model = null;
FileReader reader = null;
MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

try {
     reader = new FileReader(pomfile); // <-- pomfile is your pom.xml
     model = mavenreader.read(reader);
     model.setPomFile(pomfile);
}catch(Exception ex){
     // do something better here
     ex.printStackTrace()
}

MavenProject project = new MavenProject(model);
project.getProperties() // <-- thats what you need
```

Comment: Single-link answers are discouraged here (mostly because they can become useless when the linked-to resource goes away). You should at least summarize the information from the linked to post here.

Comment: I accidently posted the wrong link, its a stackoverflow post, that should not go away ;)

Comment: But i agree whit you, just a link is a bit unpleasant. So based on the source from the link i added some comments and the method call you are searching for (last line).

Comment: This is really a very bad practice, just use the maven resource plugin!

Comment: Why should this be bad practice if he wants to access the properties from java code?

Comment: Because the maven resource plugin does do it out of the box

Comment: But only if you assume that he wants to/could change his pom(s). I agree whith you that it might be bad to have the properties directly in the pom file instead of an external file. That file could be read with the java properties class - sure. But what in the other case? Then the maven-model is the best solution to do the trick ... but before David Dai dont tell us what exactly he wants to do we all are only guessing.

Comment: It was my understanding too that we have one mvn pom file (containing properties) and one java application (from where we want to read details of that pom file). Without actually running maven.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **build-info** goal in **spring-boot-maven-plugin**:

In my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    ...
      <execution>
        <id>build-info</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-info</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And in my code:

```
@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;

...

@GetMapping
public Map<String, String> getVersion() {
    return Map.of(
            "build.name", buildProperties.getName(), 
            "build.version", buildProperties.getVersion(), 
            "build.date", buildProperties.getTime().toString());
}
```

More information about this plugin goal can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-build-info

Answer (score -8):

You can parse the pom file with JDOM (http://www.jdom.org/).