# @MessageDriven and maven properties

Tags: java, maven, jms, ejb-3.1

How can I define **jms/MyQueue** in the following code sample using maven profile / properties?

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/MyQueue") })
public class SomeMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {
    ....
```

Comment: are you looking forward to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom?

Comment: no, that is different question

Comment: Could you please explain how.

Comment: I know how to load properties from pom.xml profile. The question is how to promote them into annotation's propertyValue. I'm not really sure what you don't understand in my original straitforward question? Please add concrete code sample of how I can achieve my goal, if this is the same topic you're pointing to

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve in the end. If your purpose is to have a queue to be used in development, I suggest a different approach, which is leave the annotations as they are and provide a specific configuration (glassfish, weblogic, etc...) pointing to the desired queue by means of maven profile.