# How to read .property file from pom.xml

Tags: java, parent-pom

I have one  parent pom.xml file and multiple child pom.xml files. 
There are multiple versions for various dependencies defined in properties> tag. I would like to move all that is written in properties> tag to ".property" file.

The issue is that pom.xml are not able to read property file.

I tried using file> tag but still no success. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify your Question, but as much as i understand is that you want to read/write a Property File in Java.

If so there is inbuild mecanisms you can use.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i want to move all the versions mentioned below to .property file and read that from pom.xml:  <jee.version>7.0</jee.version>
  <hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: @Shilpa well then you gotta read those xml property tags, via xmlparsing and write it into a properties object and save it.

Comment: Is there no other way to use some tags in pom.xml to read some ".property file" ?

Comment: @Shilpa So you want to basically do something like this right? pom.xml: " <jee.version>7.0</jee.version> <hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>" --> configuartion.property: "jee.version = 7.0 \n hibernate.version = 5.2.4". If so you should read the answer to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom

Comment: @Lavent I do not want to make use of "java" file. i check for <filer> tag as well but looks like it is not working