# Spring MVC Multi Module

Tags: spring, multi-module

I have multimodule such as;

```
<modules>
    <module>APP-Web</module>
    <module>APP-Core</module>
    <module>App-ABC</module>
    <module>App-XYZ</module>
</modules>
```

How can I get all added module names from core module class?

Comment: Can you please tell what you are trying to achieve that may provide better insight

Comment: I am trying to find all module names in my application with java code. So I can setup necessary masterdata for added module.

Comment: you can follow this link it seems to provide the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom

Comment: It can work, thanks.