# How to updates values of properties files from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

**I want to update application.properties file values from pom.xml when I run mvn test.
values must be passed from pom.xml to application.properties at runtime**
pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/phomeTestNg.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>    
            </plugins>  
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

application.properties file
    gapp=${project.build.sourceEncoding}

**java code**

```
        FileReader reader=new 
        FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\application.properties");          
        Properties p=new Properties();  
        p.load(reader);           
        System.out.println("Properties  "+p.getProperty("gapp"));
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Comment: Is this a spring boot application?

Comment: No it's simple maven project

Comment: First load your properties via classpath and not via FileReader cause that will not work in jars...So best is to use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties)`. Second which kind of values would like you to updated from your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named `properties-maven-plugin`. That creates a property file with the name you specify. And then you can directly access all the variables just like you do in any property file. It might not be the exact solution. But will give you a direction perhaps.
Here's a code sample to have a look at it. This will be your pom :

```
<properties>
    <name>${project.name}</name>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
     <foo>bar</foo>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/my.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Got this code from another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589696/7241652