# How can I print property in pom.xml of build?

Tags: java, maven

My current project profiles in pom.xml are following this.

```
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>local</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>production</id>
</profile>
<profile>
<id>development</id>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

I am looking for a way to print to check if this build is on local in .java code.
I also would like to make some functions divided.

```
System.out.println(isLocal)
/* When it in local. it should be true*/

if(isLocal)
{
XXX
}
else
{
YYY
}
```

Project is compiled like "mvn compile -P local"
in Eclipse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access maven properties defined in the pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom)

Comment: I would like to know how to check whether the project is compiled with -P local...  and `local` is defined in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do the following:

- Define a property inside the profile.
- Define a properties file in your resources.
- Use resource filtering to write the property to this properties file.
- Load the resource in your Java code and check the property within.