# MavenProject: Get the available classes for use on my plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm loading a Maven project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381460/get-mavenproject-from-just-the-pom-xml-pom-parser). I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve the source roots so I can figure out the Java classes I have so my Mojo can use them.

I tried a couple of the methods in there, like getResources or getScriptSources without luck. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I was asked to elaborate a little bit in what I'm attempting to do, so here it is:

The plugin I'm developing will take the sources in the project and create test cases from those. Unless configured, I want to generate tests for all the classes, and for that, I need to somehow figure out where are my sources so I can configure properly.

Hope that helps.

Here's the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/randoop-maven-plugin). I planned on publishing it later but I provided source as requested.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you like to achieve ?

Comment: Do you only want the source directory path, something like `../src/main/java/`?

Comment: Yes, I can scan from there for the rest. I'm not that concerned about the default /src/main/java, is more for the other sources that can be defined in the pom via plug-ins or other means.

Comment: I gave it a try but the list came back empty. I was expecting at least the default src/main/java to be listed, but got nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [plugin developers documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html)?

That page will link to [Plugins Cookbook](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/index.html) which links to [Mojo Developer Cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook) which has [The maven project, or the effective pom.](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook#MojoDeveloperCookbook-Themavenprojectortheeffectivepom) and gives you access to *org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject* object via

```
/** @parameter default-value="${project}" */
private org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject mavenProject;
```

Alternatively via Java 5 annotations

```
@Component
MavenProject project;
```

You can call *[getCompileSourceRoots()](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html)* to get a list of the directories that will be used for compilation.

You will also need to do more reading about how to setup inclusion/exclusions.  You can use other plugins as examples of how to do this, e.g. [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

If you want to use annotations, it is **very** important to make sure your pom is configured as per [using annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) and that you use annotations at the class level as well.  Mixing javadoc annotations might not work.

Comment: I did read it and tried that as well, but the getCompileSourceRoots()  returns empty list. I was expecting the src/main/java at leaset but no luck.

Comment: I already took a look at the maven-compiler-plugin and the way they do it but is equivalent to getting the MavenProject and calling getCompileSourceRoots() but also gives an empty list. The project I'm trying has one source file in the default src/main/java path.

Comment: Without access to your source (and time/inclination to hack) is as per mailing list response
* bottom up - add to your code copy-and-paste from compiler plugin
* top down - polymorph compiler plugin into your code
You should find where the problem is.

Alternatively debug step trace compiler plugin to see how/why getCompileSourceRoots() is set correctly, and do the same for your plugin.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Added repository link while I keep looking into the issue.

Comment: The above answer does work as seen my bitbucket contributions.  What doesn't work is use of Java 1.5 annotations \@Parameter (not sure if it should work) and \@Component (which should work)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to define a [mojo parameter](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html):

```
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"
 * @required
 */
private File sourceDirectory;
```

or with new [annotation based definition](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html):

```
@Parameter(required = true, defaultValue="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"}
private File sourceDirectory;
```

which should give your wished result.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to get that from the loaded MavenProject. That's already defined in the pom.

Comment: Which exactly will be done by the above definition...cause usually you will run a plugin within a maven project (life cylce).

Comment: There are ways to configure additional source folders and I was expecting that to be enclosed on the MavenProjet object in something like getSources(). But is not.

Comment: What about: http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/build-helper-maven-plugin-1.7/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/buildhelper/AddSourceMojo.java

Comment: That's an example of a plugin that adds sources to a project. I'm trying to detect that kind of things on the MavenProject object (or somewhere else)

Comment: Doesn't project.getCompileSourceRoots() fit your needs ? Returns a list of the source roots which you can iterate over.

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19906/discussion-between-javydreamercsw-and-khmarbaise)

Comment: There's a typo on your second piece of code. It should be @Parameter