# How to get maven repo location in pom file

Tags: maven

I have a maven goal which will execute a groovy file. This groovy file uses a path which is like below

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

This root path is used to build the another path which points to a jar file inside the local repository.

Unfortunately, I don't have permissions in C drive and I am using D drive. So my repository is also in D drive.

Because of this my build failed. To pass my build I am passing a command line arguments to maven like below

```
mvn clean install -Duser.home=D:\users\krishna
```

I want to know if there is a pom variable/place-holder something like {m2RepoHome} so that I can use the same variable in my groovy file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to access the property `maven.repo.local`, it should contain the path to the local repo.

Comment: @Tunaki I am getting no such property error

Comment: Wait, how did you try to access it? It's not a system property. If you're inside a Maven plugin, you can inject the `MavenProject` and get it from there with `project.getProperties()`.

Comment: @Tunaki I used it as a system property. Can you tell me how do I inject MavenProject? Can you point to an example

Comment: Could you post your `pom.xml`? It will be easier to take a look at your project this way.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot post. But in my groovy file I did MavenProject.getProperties().get("maven.repo.local") and I got no such property MavenProject for class: PropertyPackager

Comment: You can inject `MavenProject` inside your MOJO [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13574558/1743880)

Comment: That is something related to java code. I want to get the directory inside my .groovy file

Answer (score 17):

Maven provides a convenient place-holder `settings.X` where X is any element in settings.xml file.

I used `${settings.localRepository}` and it worked.

Properties section in https://maven.apache.org/settings.html explains how to use it.